# Проверка входных данных на соответствие CSS-коду

Tags: валидация, php, css, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно проверить Input, отправленный через веб-форму, на то, что входные данные являются CSS-кодом?

Comment: Писать свой маханький сервис проверки CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться валидатором [W3C Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/manual.html), результат проверки можно получить в любом удобном формате (например soap).

Еще вариант использовать, например, [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), который в случае невалидного css тоже выдаст ошибки...

Comment: Передавать POST на сторонний валидатор горячка. Да и потом, мне не нужно строгое соответствие стандартам, просто, чтобы это было в CSS формате. И я не очень представляю, разве SASS работает в качестве валидатора "чистого" CSS?

Comment: The most commonly used syntax is known as “SCSS” (for “Sassy CSS”), and is a superset of CSS3’s syntax. This means that **every valid CSS3 stylesheet** is **valid SCSS as well**. SCSS files use the extension .scss.